# Iterate over div's tables and their elements?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a div `res` which contains N table elements with Y div's with id `eye-d` inside of them..

How would I iterate over these for each table getting the eye-d.innerHTML's?

**NOTE:** `eye-d` is unique. There is many tables in the 1 `eye-d`.

Example of `eye-d`

```
<div id=​"eye-d">​
  <table border=​"0" cellpadding=​"2" cellspacing=​"1" class=​"list">​
    <tbody>​
      <tr class=​"table_text">​…​</tr>​
        <tr>​
         <td class=​"odd">​…​</td>​
         <td class=​"odd">​ABC</td>​
         <td class=​"odd">​N/A​</td>​
        </tr>​
    </tbody>​
  </table>​
</div>
```

As requested.. rephrased...

I have 1 div with an id `eye-d` then I have many tables... each of these tables have many div's with class `odd`. I want the `.innerHTML`'s of the `odd`'s for each table inside `eye-d`.

Comment: Please post some example HTML. Is the ID literally `eye-d`? IDs have to be unique.

Comment: Sorry, left that out by mistake. It's there now!

Comment: I'm a but confused. Are these `div`s now contained in a table which is contained in the `div` `res`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your id's are not unique.

You cannot have more than one `<div>` with an id of `"eye-d"`.

Id's *have* to be unique whilst the `name` property does not have to be unique. You may want to use classes instead.

`<div class="eye-d"> ... </div>`

**[[Edit]]**

The selector for those div's is as simple as `$("#eye-d table .odd")` (uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) )

If you must use raw JS then you can :

```
var div = document.getElementById("eye-d");
var tables = [];
recurse(res.childNodes, function(el) {
    if (el.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "table") {
        tables.push(el);
    }
});
// array of innerHTML of odd divs.
var oddDivs = [];
for (var i = 0, ii = tables.length; i < ii; i++) {
    recurse(tables[i].childNodes, function(el) {
        if (el.className.indexOf("odd") > 0) {
            oddDivs.push(el.innerHTML);
        }
    });
}

function recurse(nodeList, do) {
    for (var i = 0, ii = nodeList.length; i < ii; i++) {
        do(nodeList[i]);
        if (nodeList[i].childNodes.length > 0) {
            recurse(nodeList[i].childNodes, do);
        }
    }
}
```

Recurse recursively walks the node tree to and calls `do` for every element if finds. You can then search for whatever you want.

Comment: @FelixKling I can't be bother to write the cookie cutter raw JS code. But I shall please you.

Comment: Just saying, you should at least mention and link to it if you use it. I may write it in plain JS if I know the real structure ;)

Comment: eye-d is a unique div. There is no other eye-d. eye-d contains MANY tables.

Comment: @Skizit what do you want to get ? The innerHTML of all tables?  @FelixKling see how that rawJS burns :( it burns.

Comment: @Skizit: I think you have to rephrase your first sentence then. It reads like you have one div that contains a bunch tables which each contains a bunch of div's that have this ID.

Comment: @Skizit edited to reflect new HTML structure. @FelixKling Aw man I miss the days of using RAW js :(

Comment: +1 for raw JS :) (but you have to edit your last sentence...)

Comment: @Raynos What would $("#eye-d table .odd") actually return? would it return all of the odd's for every table in eye-d or?

Comment: @Skizit It would return every odd's in every table in #eye-d.

Answer (score 0):

If there are `Y` divs and by `eye-d` you mean eye- followed by a *d*igit/number, then it's as easy as `while (Y--) document.getElementById('eye-'+Y).innerHTML=...`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have:
1.  A div with an ID of *eye-d*.
2.  There are several tables inside of this div.
3.  You want to get each table and view its innerHTML.

```
var allTables = document.getElementById('eye-d').getElementsByTagName('table');  
for(i in allTables){ alert(allTables[i].innerHTML); }
```

Comment: Use this for loop to prevent looping beyond matches:
for (var i = 0; i < allTables.length; i++) {